# Set CPU time limit for process in Linux

Tags: linux, time-limiting

I'm using [`setrlimit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) to set process' CPU time limit with option `RLIMIT_CPU`. However, I noticed that idle time do not counts for this option. For example, if you [`sleep(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) forever, you'll never get `SIGKILL`ed. I need processes calling `sleep(3)` to get `SIGKILL`ed too. What can I do? (this must be done programmatically)

Comment: Why not simply `exit` instead of `sleep` in the first place ? Also, note that `SIGKILL` terminates the process immediately, it is probably better  to just `SIGTERM`, cleaning up on exit.

Comment: Because the processes that may call `sleep(3)` are from untrusted sources... It's hard to control what the program will do.

Comment: They can also handle `SIGTERM`... They should be `SIGKILL`ed.